# how to delay data view 3 second in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

this my code

```
Container(
      child: Column(
        children: jobProvider.jobs
            .map(
              (job) => JobTile(job),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    )
```

how to load this data delay for 3 seconds ? here I display the listview data, before displaying it I want to display, the

```
return Container(
           child: ProfileShimmer(),
        );
```

Comment: You can use bool value by using this value you can show your `ProfileShimmer()` for 3 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as easy as this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageWithDelayedView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageWithDelayedView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageWithDelayedViewState createState() => _PageWithDelayedViewState();
}

class _PageWithDelayedViewState extends State<PageWithDelayedView> {
  bool _initialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Schedule function call after the widget is ready to display
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _initialize();
    });
  }

  void _initialize() {
    Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      if (mounted) { // Check that the widget is still mounted
        setState(() {
          _initialized = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Text('Hold on a bit');
    }
    return Text('Yay, I\'m ready!');
  }
}
```